# How to read Daisy format book on mac?

Tags: file-format, ebook

I have downloaded an ebook which as they had mention, is in daisy format. It is a zip file containing a number of files with strange extensions. How do I read it on mac?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Calibre can read DAISY format ebooks. It can also convert various formats to EPUB, so that would be your best bet if you'd like to read it in iBooks.